# How can i disable DPM using AMD-GPU-Pro 17.50?

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics, amdgpu-pro

After having issues with both the stable version and development version of Mesa, I decided to install AMDGPU-Pro 17.50 on my Ubuntu 16.04.3 installation.

Games now run much better, but there is still brief moments of lag that I suspect are down to power management being enabled.

Does anyone know how i can disable DPM with the latest AMDGPU-Pro driver stack?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you use the Kernel parameters radeon.dpm=0 (this is for the radeon driver) amdgpu.dpm=0 (this is for amdgpu). At least this was the case a while ago, hopefully it hasn't changed in the meantime.